# Postgres - Update on single record slow on ver 10+

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a very simple table, DDL is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.next_id (
  id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  next_value int8 NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT next_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The table only has about 120 rows, and does not have any indexes apart from the primary key.

When I do the following UPDATE query in DBeaver to either of two Linux servers running either 10.5 or 11.2 of PostgreSQL, it takes approx 50ms:

```
update NEXT_ID set next_value=next_value+1 where id='Session';
```

However, if I point DBeaver at a server running 9.5.3 of PostgreSQL, it takes approx 3ms on average.

Now if I create a FOR loop as follows:

```
do $$
begin
    for i in 1..100000 loop
        update NEXT_ID set next_value=next_value+1 where id='Session';
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

It takes approx the same time (~1.5s) on all of the machines. In other words, the margin of error is probably equivalent to the extra delay experienced with the one record update.

It feels like there is some sort of overhead involved with the transaction around the statements.

How can I get more information about where PostgreSQL is spending the time?

I have tried doing an `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` on the above single record UPDATE on the 'slower' servers, and I get the following:

```
Update on next_id  (cost=0.00..2.58 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.057..0.057 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on next_id  (cost=0.00..2.58 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.043..0.044 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((id)::text = 'Session'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 125
Planning Time: 0.066 ms
Execution Time: 0.080 ms
```

Which seems to indicate that the query is actually only taking a couple of ms to plan and execute. So where is the rest of the time being taken?

All the servers involved are using the same database that has been replicated across all of them.

By the way, I'm not interested in anyone telling me that using a VARCHAR(255) for a primary key is a bad idea, as this is the same across all the servers, and it's not the point of this question.

---

UPDATE: We've noticed that a major difference between a Linux machine that is slow (mine) and another that is fast is the filesystems. My machine is using BTRFS for the filesystem where Postgres is, and the faster machine is using XFS.

A quick google of Postgres on various filesystems reveals a few people saying that using Postgres on BTRFS is (don't cross the streams!) bad.

We are going to attempt to reformat my machine to use XFS to see if that makes a difference.

In the meantime, I'm still interested in giving the bounty to anyone who can tell me how to log where the extra time is being spent.

---

UPDATE2: Following the suggestion by Nick Barnes in the comments, I ran a sequence of `BEGIN; UPDATE ...; COMMIT;` statements explicitly, and the log gave me the following output:

```
LOG:  duration: 0.025 ms  parse <unnamed>: begin
LOG:  duration: 0.014 ms  bind <unnamed>: begin
LOG:  duration: 0.003 ms  execute <unnamed>: begin
LOG:  duration: 0.045 ms  parse <unnamed>:  update NEXT_ID set next_value=next_value+1 where id='Session'
LOG:  duration: 0.055 ms  bind <unnamed>:  update NEXT_ID set next_value=next_value+1 where id='Session'
LOG:  duration: 0.059 ms  execute <unnamed>:  update NEXT_ID set next_value=next_value+1 where id='Session'
LOG:  duration: 0.004 ms  parse <unnamed>:  commit
LOG:  duration: 0.003 ms  bind <unnamed>:  commit
LOG:  duration: 50.237 ms  execute <unnamed>:  commit
```

So yes, Nick, the overhead is definitely in the COMMIT. But what is it doing? Is there any way to get more detailed information in the log about what it is doing during that 50ms?

Comment: The explain plan you showed us appears to be for a query which has `WHERE id = 'InventoryTransaction'`, which is _not_ the same logic as the update query.

Comment: Sorry, I ran the same query with several different IDs of different length to see if the length of the string ID made any difference. It didn't. So yes, the explain output is not the *exact* same as the query I posted above it, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Why did anyone vote to close this question?  It is valid and well written

Comment: "*only taking a couple of ms to plan and execute*" actually: substantially **less** than one millisecond

Comment: How exactly are you measuring those 50ms? If that is the time you see in DBeaver this will also include the round trip to the server including network latency. With the DO block you only have the network overhead once (sending the DO block) but then all processing is done on the server so you get rid of the per-statement overhead that you have from your SQL client. The same is true for the `explain analyze` output: it does not include network latency. Are the old and new servers in the same network? Are they attached to the same routers/switches?

Comment: Regarding the `varchar(255)` - my question is: why 255? Are you ware that there is no advantage over declaring the column with a length of 200, 250, 300 or 350 instead? There is no magic optimization happening when using 255 just because it's 2^8 - 1

Comment: Actually, one of the 'slow' servers is my machine, so the DBeaver connection is  'localhost', so no network involved. The fastest server is a VM in another server across the network. The other slow machine is a fellow developer's which is on the same switch. So no, i don't think the network is part of the equation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hehe, yeah, it's just me being a geek and being fixated with numbers like that. We could actually get away with `VARCHAR(50)`, and I tried changing the column to that yesterday, but it made no difference at all.

Comment: The explain plan shows that the query is looping over the rows and filtering the `id` column. It casts `id` to text for the filter, which is more effort because there isn't any other option (because it's the primary key). That is where the time is being spent.

Comment: @bruceskyaus but the execution time is 0.08ms, and besides, if it was doing that on each UPDATE, then the FOR LOOP would take a lot longer. If the 50ms was being taken up in the execution of the query, wouldn't the EXPLAIN ANALYSE show it?

Comment: Please bear in mind that explain plans are just that: a plan. Without real-time monitoring (not sure how to do that in PostgreSQL, but I've done in Oracle with TOAD). Also, because you are executing the query in a `for` loop, that complicates your analysis because `for` is not strictly SQL - making the explain plan less useful as each statement is executed separately.

Comment: Transaction overhead sounds likely, given the outcome of your `FOR` loop test, and the difference in filesystems. Try running an explicit `BEGIN; UPDATE ...; COMMIT;` and timing each statement.

Comment: @NickBarnes Yes, see my latest update. The wait is definitely in the COMMIT part.

Comment: One more thing to confirm, does setting [`fsync=off`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-FSYNC) eliminate the overhead? (I'm assuming this is a dev server, don't do this to anything important!)

Comment: @NickBarnes Actually, someone on the pg_performance mailing list has suggested `synchronous_commit=off' instead (as it is safer, apparently), and that has got rid of the 50ms overhead on my machine. So I'm pretty sure that the BTRFS file system is to blame for the overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UPDATE` itself is fairly cheap; before the transaction is committed, there is no need for your new data to survive a crash, so the changes are only made to in-memory buffers (which the server flushes to disk at its leisure).

It's not until you commit the transaction that the server needs to give you a guarantee of durability. Postgres handles crash safety using a [write-ahead log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-intro.html) (WAL), and when you `COMMIT`, you're waiting for the WAL to be synchronously written to disk.

This makes the commit latency highly dependent on the file system and the underlying hardware, and if your PG10 instance is waiting around for BTRFS to finish a copy-on-write or something, that could certainly account for the difference you're seeing.

To confirm that this is the cause, you can skip the synchronous disk write by disabling [`fsync`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-FSYNC) (though this puts you at risk of data corruption, so be sure to test it on a throwaway instance). A safer and less intrusive option is to [`SET LOCAL synchronous_commit = off`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-COMMIT) at the start of your transaction, which should have the same effect, provided you don't have synchronous replication running.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'm going to accept your answer at this stage as it gives a good explanation of why the commit has this overhead. I'm going to leave the bounty for a few days to see if anyone can give me an answer on how to specifically pinpoint, and log, where the extra time is being spent. Because even though we know that the COMMIT is taking the time, I would want to know (as I'm sure others would too) where the COMMIT time is being spent.

Comment: No problem! Unfortunately, even with `log_min_messages = DEBUG5`, Postgres doesn't seem to give any breakdown of what's going on within the `COMMIT`. I'm not sure how else you'd get a definitive answer, short of breaking out the profiler and diving into the source code...